# How to get user from transaction log file In SQL Server (.ldf file) without app like ApexSqlLog

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How I can get the user from transaction log file in SQL Server?

I tried this query but it isn't giving me the right user

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN (SELECT NAME 
          FROM SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS lgn 
         WHERE Rtrim(lgn.SID) = Rtrim(log2.[TRANSACTION SID])) IS NOT 
       NULL THEN 
  'login: ' 
+ Upper((SELECT NAME FROM SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS lgn WHERE Rtrim(lgn.SID) 
  = Rtrim 
(log2.[TRANSACTION SID]))) 
  ELSE 'db user: ' 
       + Upper((SELECT NAME FROM SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS lgn WHERE Rtrim( 
       lgn.SID) 
       = Rtrim(log2.[TRANSACTION SID] ))) 
END 
AS 'Login_or_User', 
log1.*, 
CASE log1.__$OPERATION 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'DELETE' 
  WHEN 2 THEN 'INSERT' 
  WHEN 4 THEN 'UPDATED VALUE' 
  WHEN 3 THEN 'PREVIOUS UPDATED VALUE' 
  ELSE NULL 
END 
AS operation, 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), log2.[BEGIN TIME])                                                                                                                 AS 'Begin Time',
LEFT(log.ALLOCUNITNAME, Charindex('.', log.ALLOCUNITNAME) - 1) 
AS 'Schema', 
LEFT(RIGHT(log.ALLOCUNITNAME, Len(log.ALLOCUNITNAME) - 
                                   Charindex('.', log.ALLOCUNITNAME)), 
Charindex('.', RIGHT(log.ALLOCUNITNAME, 
Len(log.ALLOCUNITNAME) 
- 
                                                                                                               Charindex('.', log.ALLOCUNITNAME))) - 1) AS 'Object',
SYS.Fn_cdc_hexstrtobin(Substring(log.[CURRENT LSN], 1, 8) 
                       + Substring(log.[CURRENT LSN], 10, 8) 
                       + 
Substring(log.[CURRENT LSN], 19, 4))                                                                                           currentlsn
  FROM DBO.TEMPTABLE log1 
       LEFT JOIN ::FN_DBLOG(NULL, NULL) log 
              ON log1.__$SEQVAL = SYS.Fn_cdc_hexstrtobin( 
                                  Substring(log.[CURRENT LSN], 1, 8) 
                                  + Substring(log.[CURRENT LSN], 10, 8) 
                                  + Substring(log.[CURRENT LSN], 19, 4)) 
       LEFT JOIN ::FN_DBLOG(NULL, NULL)log2 
              ON log.[TRANSACTION ID] = log2.[TRANSACTION ID] 
       LEFT JOIN SYS.ALLOCATION_UNITS au 
              ON log.ALLOCUNITID = au.ALLOCATION_UNIT_ID 
       LEFT JOIN SYS.PARTITIONS p 
              ON p.PARTITION_ID = au.CONTAINER_ID 
       LEFT JOIN SYS.OBJECTS so 
              ON so.OBJECT_ID = p.OBJECT_ID 
       LEFT JOIN SYS.SERVER_PRINCIPALS spa 
              ON spa.SID = log2.[TRANSACTION ID]
```

This Code For Checking Database That Has CDC(CHange Data Capture) Enabled Then Choose Specific Table To Get The Changes On it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? what is `Log2` ?

Comment: You don't typically read the transaction log file - that's an **internal** SQL Server file and there is no documented API to read the transaction log file directory. The code you have also doesn't read the transaction log file, by the way... What are you trying to do that you cannot do otherwise?!?!?

Comment: I wanna Get Who Change Data (Insert-Delete-Update) Using Cdc(CHange Data Capture) But u Can't Get The User Using Log File Of Specific DataBase << Thats My Last Updated Of The Procedure I Makeing >>

Comment: @alex - It looks like log2 is an alias for the undocumented (but very useful) sys.fn_dblog function. Marc - That does read out of the transaction log

Comment: Yea we both commented before he put something relevant in his question

Answer (score 0):

You could always put a trigger on the table to capture the PK, getdate(), and the suser_id() of any user who inserts, updates, or deletes data against that table.  You could then track that along with CDC to get you want you want.  I realize people want to stay away from triggers but its a simple and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUSER_SNAME([Transaction SID])
FROM ::fn_dblog(null, null)
WHERE [Operation] = 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT'
```

The result will be 'DomainName\UserName'